# How to compare multi column values with other multi column value of same dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to match `a1` `a2` from the row whose `a3` is missing with the entire column of `b1 b2 b3` where ever `a1 a2` matches with any two `b's` value we will grab the 3rd `b` value i.e in row 2 `a1=84` and `a2=5` which is a match for `b's` in row 3 where `b1=5` and `b2=84` so now we will grab the value `b3=89` in this case. Similarly for row 5 we will grab the value of `b2=66`.

this is just a small data set actual data contains millions of rows.

| time | duration | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 | 95 | 11 | 2 | 3 | 22 | 67 | 25 |
| 2022-02-27 | 85 | 84 | 5 |  | 72 | 23 | 15 |
| 2022-02-26 | 87 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 5 | 84 | 89 |
| 2022-02-25 | 72 | 9 | 10 | 44 | 55 | 78 | 41 |
| 2022-02-24 | 66 | 19 | 57 |  | 50 | 60 | 51 |
| 2022-02-23 | 88 | 20 | 48 | 67 | 19 | 66 | 57 |

[image]

Comment: please add your sample data as text to your question, not as image.

Comment: Hi  @Rabinzel I have added table as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all permutations of `b` columns, left join with original DataFrame filtered only rows with missing values in `a3` for `a3_` column wich match `a1, a2` in list. Then join list to one Series, remove possible duplicates in index and replace missing values of `a3` column in original DataFrame:

```
from  itertools import permutations

cols = ['b1','b2','b3']
L = [df[df['a3'].isna()].merge(df.loc[:, x].set_axis(['a1','a2','a3'], axis=1),
              how='left', on=['a1','a2'], suffixes=('','_'))['a3_'].dropna()
     for x in permutations(cols, 3)]

final = pd.concat(L)
final = final[~final.index.duplicated()]
print (final)
4    66.0
1    89.0
Name: a3_, dtype: float64

df['a3'] = df['a3'].fillna(final)
print (df)
          time  duration  a1  a2    a3  b1  b2  b3
0  2022-02-28         95  11   2   3.0  22  67  25
1  2022-02-27         85  84   5  89.0  72  23  15
2  2022-02-26         87   6   7   8.0   5  84  89
3  2022-02-25         72   9  10  44.0  55  78  41
4  2022-02-24         66  19  57  66.0  50  60  51
5  2022-02-23         88  20  48  67.0  19  66  57
```

Answer (score 1):

I use to code algorithm by hand trying to be readable and understandable.
Here is an old geek fashion code with the following algoritm:

if a1,a2 are in b1,b2,b3 respective products are a1*a2 and a1*a2*the third element.

the thirdElement is exactly b1*b2*b3//a1*a2 if the remainder is 0. (notice integer division).
As a1*a2 can be equal to several bx*by , check too that a1+a2 == bx+by (where bx+by is (b1+b2+b3 - third element) ).
(a3 is set to None here, could be "" depending of your data )

```
tests = [ \
["2022-02-28",95,11,2,3,22,67,25],\
["2022-02-27",85,84,5,None,72,23,15],\
["2022-02-26",87,6,7,8,5,84,89],\
["2022-02-25",72,9,10,44,55,78,41],\
["2022-02-24",66,19,57,None ,50,60,51],\
["2022-02-23",88,20,48,67,19,66,57]\
]
# first collect products and sums of all b
storeb1b2b3 =[]
storesumb1b2b3 = []
for test in tests:
    storeb1b2b3.append(test[5]*test[6]*test[7])
    storesumb1b2b3.append(test[5]+test[6]+test[7])

# now loop on a1 a2 and check in all b 
for ia in range(0,len(tests)):
    test = tests[ia] 
    # check a3 empty
    if (test[4] != None):
        continue
    a1= test[2]
    a2 = test[3]
    a1a2 =a1*a2
    # check against all b 
    for ib in range(0,len(storeb1b2b3)):
        b1b2b3= storeb1b2b3[ib]
        sumb1b2b3 = storesumb1b2b3[ib]
        if (b1b2b3 % a1a2 == 0):
            candidate =(b1b2b3//a1a2)
            if ((sumb1b2b3 - candidate) == (a1+a2)):
                print ( "for",a1,a2,"at",tests[ia][0],"found: ",candidate, "at ",tests[ib])
```

Notes :
products and sum of b are calculated once at begining to optimize. If a too long list to be stored, can be calculated on the fly in a1a2 loops.
Use indices ia, ib to be able to print source lines.

```
for 84 5 at 2022-02-27 found:  89 at  ['2022-02-26', 87, 6, 7, 8, 5, 84, 89]
for 19 57 at 2022-02-24 found:  66 at  ['2022-02-23', 88, 20, 48, 67, 19, 66, 57]
```

### Hope you enjoy coding too :)

**addendum** : someone asks me to prove that if **ab=a'b'** and **a+b=a'+b'** then pair [a,b] is unique.
Demonstration.

> ab = a'b' and a+b = a'+b'
> if a = a' , as (a+b = a'+b') => b = b' : they are same numbers.
> if a != a' => a' = a + x, as (a+b = a'+b') => b' = b - x
> products are :
> ab = (a+x)*(b-x) = ab - xa + xb -x2 = ab +x(-a+b-x).
> x(-a+b-x) = 0.
> two cases :
> 1) x = 0 so a'= a+0 and b' = b-0  still same values a,b.
> 2) -a+b-x = 0
> x = b-a
> so a'= a+x = b.
> b'= b-x = a
> just a permutation of a,b  in b,a
> => in any case if (ab = a'b')and (a+b=a'+b') this is always the same pair [a,b].

**QED**